Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS - Installation failed
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04,  but after the installation when I restart, the PC goes in Boot mode and Ubuntu is not recognized. I retried the installation and at the end the installation I go in Ubuntu testing and I see the following error on 2 services of Ubuntu:
FAILED to start plymounth-reboot service  
FAILED unmounting cdroom.mount  
FAILED to start casper.service  
FAILED to execute shutdown binary  

At this point I tried to reinstall these services, but the problem is not fixed.

Start a Live session. After the upload is complete, open a terminal. In it, run: sudo inxi -F Copy the output, edit your post, and paste it into it

Those are way further down the failure line, and have nothing to do with the actual error here. You'll need to use the GRUB menu (hold ctrl at boot if it doesn't automatically appear) and use the recovery mode kernel. Then journalctl -b or dmesg to find out what the actual error is further up.
If I had to speculate, your BIOS is old (check for firmware updates), your disk is failing (check SMART), something doesn't support ACPI properly (check BIOS settings and unplug all but only the most necessary devices), or one of your devices needs a different driver to work.
